# I got Initialization error in Cucumber with maven and selenium

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

**Test Runner**
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="features",glue={"stepDefinition"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

**MyApplication.feature**

```
Feature: Test test smoke scenario

  Scenario Outline: Test  login with valid credentials
    Given open fireFox and start application
    When I enter valid "username" and valid "password"
    Then User should be able to login successfully

Examples: 
      | username   | password          |
      | 9739817000 | mnbvcxz  |
      | 9739817001 | mnbvcxz1  |
      | 9739817002 | mnbvcxz2  |
```

**Maven POM**

```
<groupId>demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>prac</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>prac</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
  

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

**Smoke.java**

```
public class Smoke {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Given("^open fireFox and start application$")
    public void open_fireFox_and_start_application() throws Throwable {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://testweb.com");
        
    }

    @When("^I click on Login$")
    public void I_click_on_Login() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Login')]")).click();
        

    }

    @When("^enter valid \"([^\"]*)\" and valid \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void enter_valid_and_valid(String un, String pwd) throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys(un);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(pwd);
        
    }

    @Then("^Click on Login$")
    public void Click_on_Login() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginUser")).click();
        
    }
    @Then("^User should be able to login successfully$")
    public void User_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() throws Throwable {
        
       
    }
```

These above are the test runner,feature file,Smoke test class.
Its throwing an Initilization error.I am new to Cucumber and recheck all the maven dependency ,its correct only.But even also its giving error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc1Zv.png)

Comment: Do you have the gherkin.jar present in your maven dependencies? The class in the error is contained in this jar.

Comment: yes ,its automatically adding while adding the cucumber dependency

Answer (score 0):

As, you have not specified any sets of data for your feature file, you do not need to use **Scenario Outline**. You can use it when you need to execute same scenario with different sets of data. Hence, remove **Scenario Outline** from your feature file (shown below the updated feature file) and retry:

```
Feature: Test Milacron smoke scenario

Scenario: Test  login with valid credentials
Given open fireFox and start application
When I enter valid "username" and valid "password"
Then User should be able to login successfully
```

Please refer to [link](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference) for more details about writing feature files. Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your pom file is absolutely fine.

Here you are using Scenario Outline if you are using Scenario outline there should be Examples annotation in the feature file. Anyways your test scenario can be achieved without using scenario outline

Update feature file and java file with below code:

Myapplication.feature:
Feature: Test test smoke scenario

```
  Scenario: Test  login with valid credentials
     Given open fireFox and start application
     When I click on Login
     When I enter valid "username" and valid "password"
     Then I click on Loginbutton
     Then User should be able to login successfully
```

Smoke.java:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class Smoke {
   WebDriver driver;
@Given("^open fireFox and start application$")
public void open_fireFox_and_start_application() throws Throwable {
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://testweb.com");

}

 @When("^I click on Login$")
    public void I_click_on_Login() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Login')]")).click();
    }

@When("^I enter valid \"([^\"]*)\" and valid \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_enter_valid_and_valid(String arg1, String arg2) throws   Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys(arg1);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(arg2);
}


@Then("^I click on Loginbutton$")
public void Click_on_Login() throws Throwable {
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginUser")).click();

}
@Then("^User should be able to login successfully$")
public void User_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() throws Throwable {


}
}
```

Maintain Folder structure as mentioned in the attached image
[image]

If you want to use scenario outline update feature file like below
Same smoke.java file will works in this case.

```
Feature: Test test smoke scenario

 Scenario Outline: Test  login with valid credentials
  Given open fireFox and start application
  When I click on Login
  When I enter valid "<username>" and valid "<password>"
  Then I click on Loginbutton
  Then User should be able to login successfully

Examples:
  |username|password|
  |test|test|
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: yes its working but when i added scenario outline and try to do data driven then same error occurs

Comment: Even after putting angular bracket also i am getting initialization error

Comment: I verified it in my machine it was working fine did you copied same code as mentioned above?

Comment: No,i have just add angular bracket

Comment: Please try to copy everything then it may fix your issues in my machine its working fine

Comment: Yes,its not working for me ...i am getting same error 


Rerun runner.TestRunner.initializationError
initializationError(runner.TestRunner)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)

 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

Comment: Please find my project which i tested in my local machine in below path
https://ufile.io/f857c

Comment: Thanks but for me still same issue persist

Comment: Did you imported my maven project and ran TestRunner.java file?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario Outline is used to pass different sets of input data to your scenario. For instance 'ABC' and 'PWD' are your username, password respectively then update your feature file as below,

```
Feature: Test Milacron smoke scenario
Scenario Outline: Test  login with valid credentials
Given open fireFox and start application
When I enter valid "username" and valid "password"
Then User should be able to login successfully

Examples:
 | username      | password |
 | ABC           |  PWD     |
```

Comment: Even after adding the parameters for data driven testing its giving same error

Comment: Please share your project structure Rakesh, it helps to fix. Actually I tried same code its working fine.

Comment: Your Project structure is perfect, I hope this error  ".runner.TestRunner.initializationError initializationError(runner.TestRunner) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter" is related to gherkin dependency only. Give a try by including below dependency in your POM and build project , if possible restart eclipse again.

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Now its giving following error:
Class not found runner.TestRunner
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: runner.TestRunner
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: Perform Project --> Clean or maven clean install

Comment: No,its still persisting

Comment: ClassNotFoundException occurs if runnable class is not loaded properly.
Possible solutions for this is,

1. Clean your project or all your projects in workspace.
1. Make sure your classpath environment variable set to 'JAVA_HOME\lib'
2. Open your classpath file and check below steps are there or not?

  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove the empty feature files (those without any scenarios present) from the features directory.